# How to handle duplicate data points in k-Nearest Neighbor algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction, knn

I have a large data-set on which I am running k-Nearest Neighbor classification algorithm. Consider a scenario k=3, I have a new (unclassified) point 'x', I find 3 nearest neighbors n1, n2, n3.

The problem is if n1, n2, n3 all have the exact same features, i.e. they are duplicate data points. In my case this is a movie database where n1, n2, n3 are three customers who has watched exactly same movies, same number of times.

So Do I have to consider them separately? OR should I consider them as one data point and look for 2 more unique data points?

Comment: Why do you want to treat them separately? Is there anything special about them?

Comment: Because they are actually three different customers, which may differ in some other attributes like location, income, gender etc. Which is not being considered if we are limiting our score to their watched movies history.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is more correct than the other.

Mathematically it is common to assume points with identical features to be the same point. But then it may have *multiple labels* and weights, so this is more expensive to handle.

Intuitively, and from a database view, the *k* nearest neighbors should be *k* objects, no matter if they are the same or not. There *is* more than one "President George Bush", fact. Why *merge* them? If you wanted more objects, you should have chosen a larger k.

Choose whichever you prefer, but do not assume everybody made the same decision.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using it for.

If you're trying to see who has watched the same movies the same number of times, then you'd want to treat them as discrete points, because although they are duplicated points, they are still the nearest neighbors.

If you want to see an aggregate of how many times a movie has been watched, then duplicated points should be treated as one point.

Hope this helps,
--Varun